# ElasticSearch .net avoid DynamicDictionary

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am tasked to build a rather generic ElasticSearch Connector for an internal C#-Project. The Primary purpose of the connector is to get all the data from an external ElasticSearch source, transform it to a column-row format and pass it on. 
While my connector can do all that it is a rather slow process, profiling seems to indicate that the culprit is the lavish usage of dynamic C#-objects, returned by ElasticSearch.Net-API.

The documentation for ElasticSearch.Net has an explixit warning that the DynamicDictionary is slow.
http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/handling-responses.html

So my question is: Is there a way to circumvent the dynamic dictionary? I would be totally satisfied with a simple Dict(String, Object). I cannot use nest or other techniques to build a POCO because the I don't know the results from ElasticSearch before - I can literally be any format and my job is to pass it on to another program.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the documentation you are referring also says that

> If you specify T as string or byte[] the response will not go through the registered ISerializer but simply read and returned.

So you can take the bytes and then do whatever you want, for example parse them with JSON parser of your choice that extracts what you need without too much overhead.